# Inspecting xpaths with the new Chrome 109

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, web-inspector

Company recently updated to Chrome 109, so I got the new Chromedriver (selenium) 109.
I always use the inspect on the web page in Chrome to find xpaths, check xpaths, etc.
Whereas in previous Chrome versions when you did the inspect (or f12) there were 3 little dots to anchor your inspect window.  You could anchor it to the side of the html window, on the bottom, or separate from the Chrome window, but with 109 it only allows separate.  Is that true?  It opens up a full new window.  You can click the "Restore Down" and it makes it smaller but still not under the window.

Is this a new feature (or bug) of Chrome where it no longer lets you do this? (And yes I know chromedriver really has nothing to do with this)

Comment: My Chrome is 109.0.5414.75.
I can choose separate, left, bottom, right.
Can you post an image of your Chrome inspect window?

Comment: Strange.  yesterday it wasn't working but now it seems to be.

Comment: Actually, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: If you don't currently have the problem, I think you can close this question.